# German law: Food in a coffee shop

Tags: germany, food, drugs

I am planning to open a coffee shop in the near future (as soon as it becomes legal).
I don´t ask for help about the entire coffee shop thing, however I want to know which requirements I must meet to also sell self made (or bought) baked THC goods there.
Would this be part of the [Gaststättengesetz](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/gastg/BJNR004650970.html)?
I also plan to deliver them.
Does someone know which requirements I need to meet to sell and deliver the self made (or bought) baked goods?

Comment: I suggest you ask your *Gewerbeamt*. That will give you much more reliable information than you can get from random people on the internet.

Comment: Coffee shop in the Dutch sense, I presume?  In much of the English-speaking world a coffee shop is a kind of restaurant or indeed just a shop that sells coffee.

Comment: @phoog Yes, coffee shop in the dutch sense.

Comment: Sorry, but since the law that you will rely on (making cannabis legal) is not yet passed, any answer can only be speculation. Voting to close.

Comment: Why are we using euphemisms?  Cannabis and coffee are two different things, please say what you mean.  Most of us are adults and can handle the truth.

Comment: Sure, go ahead and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this draft](https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/fileadmin/Dateien/3_Downloads/Gesetze_und_Verordnungen/GuV/C/Kabinettvorlage_Eckpunktepapier_Abgabe_Cannabis.pdf), the sale would be highly regulated. They plan to *evaluate* an extension to edibles, so this is not clear yet. And the shops would have to be distinct from other *Genussmittel*, i.e. alcohol or tobacco. A delivery service seems impossible.

So while I can understand that you want to move early in a new market, your business plan should wait for the details of the law. As the proverb goes, no law leaves parliament the way it went in.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I want to evaluate the amount of requirements I would need to match though, so if someone is able to speculate about that it would help already. Maybe if the situation is compared to a regular shop, which wants to sell normal baked goods? I know this is vague, but I want to plan as much as possible before the law rolls out, so it would already help if someone knows about the regulations on selling self made food and delivering it.

Comment: @Ehrenmann, from what I read in the drug liberalization debate, they **won't** make THC cookies just another over-the-counter food. You would be hard-pressed to label the exact dosage if you simply make your own dough. So the options are to find out how to run a bakery, and to **hope** you'd be allowed to add cannabis to the menu, or to learn how to run a pharmacy.

Comment: I see, that is dissapointing. Thanks for your help though :)